# Comment picker for edits

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

I find myself quite often in a situation where I edit a question or an answer and I would like to also leave a comment explaining reasons behind my edit so that a user can also understand and maybe don't do the same mistake again. Also 9 of 10 situations are similar, if not the same, like those I already went through in the past.

- removing a tag from a title
- removing an IDE tag from tags where it's not relevant to the question
- formatting code posted as a plain text
- ...

I would like to have there a picker with standard and custom comments so that I edit a post, select a comment if needed and it would post the comment below the post on save.

I know that many people do these tasks every day and do not leave an explaining comment, I don't do it myself when accessing SO via phone, for example. I believe that this feature would help to spread some basic rules among new users as they tend to not read them directly.

Comment: Do you mean there should be an option to pick a comment from the list of common comments so that you don't need to re-type comments again?

Comment: It's not a duplicate. It's a different thing. I'm not interested in "edit summary". A new user won't get any explanation based on the "improved title. added tags" summary. I propose a whole new thing. A possibility to leave a comment along with edit automatically.

Comment: @hims056 Exactly. I want a new user to know what mistake have he made and I don't want to store it in a text file on a computer or phone. Something like "Tags should not be part of a question title if ... check out other SO rules here and there ...". What would want to write this 20x a day or have to open a local file and copy-paste?

Comment: Such feature is not available. But there is [a very useful userscript](http://stackapps.com/q/2116/11265) which serves the purpose you want.

Comment: @hims056 I'm well aware of that not being available right now, that's why it's a feature-request. Thank you for that link, at least something. However I still think that it could find its place in SE TODO list.